# MS Access - Filtering a combo box to only show values that aren't in use

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm building an asset register for my work's mobile phones and phone numbers using MS Access. Everything is currently working, but I'd like to make it more user friendly.

I have 3 main tables: tblusers, tbldevices, and tblservices.

I assign an `id` from `tbldevices` and `user` from `tblusers` to `tblservices.device_id` and `tbservices.user_id`

`tbldevices.id` and `tblservices.device_id` are in a 1:1 relationship so each device can only be added to one service at a time and vice versa.

[Here are my relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr9wv.png)

[Here is the form being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PEvz.png)

My goal: when I'm on the form where I 'attach' a device to a service, I only want devices that are not being used to display in the 'Select New Device' combo box.

Comment: Check out the Find Unmatched query wizard or try: `SELECT ID FROM tbldevices WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM tblservices)`

Comment: Thanks @June7 that works well, but now the currently attached device does not show in the combo box as it is found in tblservices. Is there an OR query that can be added to easily allow it in the output?

Comment: e.g. ```SELECT ID FROM tbldevices WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM tblservices) OR is the current device..```

Comment: Yes. However, would be issue for new record. So try: `SELECT ID FROM tblDevices WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM tblservices) OR ID = Nz([device_id],0)`.

Comment: This works by showing the device_id that is attached, however, it only works for the first record on the form. Any subsequent record shows the device_id of the one in the first record. I hope that makes sense. 
Do I need to add a refresh on record change or something?

Comment: Probably have to requery the combobox. Use OnCurrent event and also maybe combobox AfterUpdate event. Me.comboboxname.Requery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @June7 for all the tips.

Ended up using

```
SELECT tbldevices.id
FROM tbldevices
WHERE (((Exists (SELECT device_id FROM [tblservices] WHERE tbldevices.ID = tblservices.device_id ))=False)) OR ((([tbldevices.id])=Nz([device_id],0)));
```

Which worked as expected.